# Accumulate 2D numpy arrays into a 3D tensor, then average them all element-wise after

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray, tensor, elementwise-operations

### Accumulation stage

In the script, the same-sized data matrix `X` is re-estimated by some model (here just a random number generator (RNG)) and accumulated/saved in a matrix `Y` over the course of a finite number of trials `t`.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import random
import pandas as pd

k = 3 #shape
t = 5 #trials
Y = np.zeros((t,k,k)) 

for i in range(5):
    X = random((k,k))   #2D estimate
    X = pd.DataFrame(X)
    Y[i,:,:] = X        #3D tensor
```

### Reduction stage

Afterwards, how do I then apply an element-wise reduction of all accumulated 2d `X` arrays inside the 3d `Y` tensor into a single 2d matrix `Z` that is the same shape as `X`? An example reduction is the average of all the individual `X` elements reduced into `Z`:

```
Z[0,0] = average of: {the first Z[0,0], second Z[0,0], ... , fifth Z[0,0]}
```

I'd prefer no element-by-element loops, if possible. I showed the **accumulation stage** using numpy arrays because I don't think pandas DataFrames can be 3d tensors, being restricted to 2d inputs only,  but can the **arithmetic reduction stage** (averaging across accumulated arrays) be done as a pandas DataFrame operation?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

Toy example:

```
test = np.arange(12).reshape(-1,2,3)
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]]])
```

Solution

```
np.apply_over_axes(np.mean,test,0).reshape(test.shape[1],test.shape[2])
array([[3., 4., 5.],
    [6., 7., 8.]])
```

And IIRC I think you're correct, `pandas` cannot really handle 3d tensors unless you mess about with Multi-indices, so personally I would rather deal with this operation in `numpy` first and then convert it to a `dataframe`. You can convert `dataframe`s to numpy via `to_numpy()`.